# Doctrine 2 Caching Workflow

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm

I am new to caching

- What should I cache

  - eg. Do I cache user info? eg. since they are frequently used throughout the application (like in the header saying "welcome {username}")?
  - But most things should be used quite frequently anyways? eg. Users have projects. These projects don't belong to everyone, but they will be frequently used by specific users do I cache them too? Won't I be caching nearly everything then?
- Also regarding CRUD, with doctrine queries, I can just use `$query->useResultCache(true)` but what happens when I update/delete an entity? I need to somehow update my cache too? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic principle of caching is to hold frequently used data that doesnt change often in memory to reduce database work.

Its more convenient to use the php session variables to hold basic things like username.

In case of projects, if they dont change often, and retrieved by users frequently, it would be a good idea to cache them. How long a project info stays cached depends on the change frequency.

Also note that if the info you present to users is vital or time important, you should use caching cautiously.

Check this reference page for basic information on caching http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#cache-related-api

Or check http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/caching.html for detailed explanation.